# What is considered a bandwidth limit in heroku?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

I want to deploy a react app to heroku using node.js as a server and serving my front-end using as static file
.. as I read heroku bandwidth is limited to 2tb a month for a certain plan, what are the actions that increment this bandwidth ? Requests to domain (more users more bandwidth) ? Serving the app to client  (regardless of the app size) ? Making certain request to the node server like authentication and Data fetching from api ? Or everything mentioned ?

Comment: In this context, bandwidth generally refers to [amount of data transferred](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwidth_(computing)#Network_consumption).

Comment: @Chris the problem is I don't know what heroku consider a bandwidth to begin with they set 2tb limit but limit to what ? server actions ? site get requests ?